# Waitfor/pause commands for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I'm running a sql script, that runs consecutive queries, how do I make sql server wait for each preceding query to finish before running the next one, assuming I have no idea how long it will take.  So rather than use the waitfor command 'hh,mm,ss' I'd like to tell SQL to only run the next query when the first one is complete.

For example, Create Table..., Insert Into..., and then a Select... query.  Since Insert Into generally takes a while due to the sheer volume of my data, how do I pause the Select query until Insert Into execution is complete?

Comment: That should be the default behavior.  Are you seeing something different?

Comment: And you use GO to say process this batch of statements and then move on to the next one

Comment: D. Stanley, if I don't run one process at a time, I get an error message. Otherwise it runs fine.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error message

Answer (score 0):

something like this ...

```
create table #temp(col1 int)
insert into #temp(col1) values(1)
select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

should always work no matter how many inserts you make or how long that takes because the statesments are executed sequentially ... no need to wait.